# Declaring 2D numpy array with unknown size

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I m new to numpy. I m trying to define a 2-d numpy array to read images, the size of which varies.So, i cant predefine the size of the array. My code is

```
np.ndarray(np.float64) I
for i in range(len(filename)):
    I=imread(filename)     //reading an image here
    I1=I.resize(256,256)   //resizing the image
```

Please suggest the corrections to the code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with just `I = imread(filename)`? Everything else seems superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the size before-hand, then don't use a numpy array to accumulate the values. Use a flexible container (e.g. a `list`) and then convert to a numpy array afterwards.

If you're working with something really large, there's also `numpy.fromiter` which will behave quite a bit more efficiently, but you'll have to jump through a couple of hoops to use it with >1D arrays.

As an example of the first suggestion, let's say we're creating an array that will always have 10 columns, but we have no way of knowing how many rows there are.  We'll use a list to store each row, and then convert to a 2D array at the end:

```
import numpy as np

data = []

random_val = 1
while random_val > 0.05:
    data.append(np.arange(10))
    random_val = np.random.random()

data = np.array(data)
print data.shape
```

Comment: I'm wondering why the downvote...